# Unity Library size getting bigger and bigger

Tags: unity

Why is unity library folder size getting bigger and bigger. Once i delete all the folder then its double the size according to my asset size. Now i made several build and my size almost reaching to 50GB. is there any bug in unity libaray?

Comment: The library folder contains a cache of processed assets and code, before unused assets have been stripped and the rest compressed together during build export, so it's not unusual for it to grow in size. Can you walk us through a repro case that leads to unbounded growth without new assets being added, or any similar indication of a bug?

Comment: I didn't add new asset but make different scenes.

Comment: Scenes are assets.